# Java quicksort program not sorting array, arrayoutofbounds exception

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm working on learning the quicksort algorithm. I am unsure where I'm going wrong. I believe I have implemented this algorithm correctly as for some random values it sorts, but others it does not. When trying to debug this problem I have changed the size of my array to 3 instead of the initial 20. Here is my current implementation:

```
public class Quicksort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Generate a random array of integers to sort
        // Integer[] numbers = new Integer[20];
        // testing int, above is original
        Integer[] numbers = new Integer[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        }

        // Print unsorted array
        printArray(numbers);

        // Sort array
        quicksort(numbers);

        // Print sorted array
        printArray(numbers);
    }

    // Print a comma-separated list of the elements in array
    public static <T> void printArray(T[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + (i < array.length - 1 ? ", " : "\n"));
        }
    }

    // Print a comma-separated list of the elements in array drawing attention to
    // the pivot and bounds of the partition
    public static <T> void printArrayPartition(T[] array, int low, int high, int pivot) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String element = "" + array[i];
            if (i == pivot)
                element = "*" + element + "*";
            if (i == low)
                element = "[" + element;
            if (i == high)
                element += "]";
            System.out.print(element + (i < array.length - 1 ? ", " : "\n"));
        }
    }

    // This is a shortcut to call the recursive quicksort on the entire array
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quicksort(T[] array) {
        quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }

    // Recursively quicksort a partition of the array
    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void quicksort(T[] array, int low, int high) {
        // If high is greater than low, then there are at least two elements in this
        // partition and it needs to be sorted. Otherwise it contains at most 1 element
        // and is therefore already sorted.
        if (low < high) {
            int pivotIndex = partition(array, low, high);
            // Uncomment printArrayPartition to print the array after every partition
            // (helpful for debugging). Every element within the partition (enclosed by [])
            // should appear on the correct side of the pivot value (marked by **)
            printArrayPartition(array, low, high, pivotIndex);

            // Quicksort the left and right partitions
            quicksort(array, low, pivotIndex - 1);
            quicksort(array, pivotIndex + 1, high);
        }
    }

    // Split a partition of the array into two new partitions and one pivot. The
    // left partition includes everything less than the pivot, and the right
    // partition is everything greater than or equal to the pivot (excluding the
    // pivot, which remains between the two partitions). Returns the index of the
    // pivot.
    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int partition(T[] array, int low, int high) {
        // Use the last element of the partition as the pivot
        T pivotValue = array[high];

        //int pivot = (int) pivotValue;

        // This marks the index AFTER the end of the (new) left partition. Right now
        // there is no left partition, so it's at the beginning of the partition we're
        // currently splitting up.
        int left = low;

        // For each element in the partition (except the pivot)
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            // Compare the current element to the pivot (high)
            if (array[i].compareTo(pivotValue) < 0) {
                // If the current element is less than the pivot, swap it with the leftmost
                // unpartitioned element (making it part of the left partition) and update the
                // left partition
                swap(array, left, i);
                left++;
            }
        }
        // Swap the pivot with the leftmost unpartitioned element. The unpartitioned
        // elements are now the right partition.
        swap(array, high, left);

        // Return the new index of the pivot
        return left;
    }

    // Swap the elements of array at index a and index b
    private static <T> void swap(T[] array, int a, int b) {
        T temp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = temp;
    }
}
```

Compilation error message I'm receiving:

```
58, 89, 53
[*53*, 89, 58]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Quicksort.swap(Quicksort.java:103)
    at Quicksort.partition(Quicksort.java:89)
    at Quicksort.quicksort(Quicksort.java:54)
    at Quicksort.quicksort(Quicksort.java:62)
    at Quicksort.quicksort(Quicksort.java:45)
    at Quicksort.main(Quicksort.java:15)
```

I fail to see the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are trying to access index 3 which is out of bounds for an array of size 3, indices start at 0 and end at (size - 1), therefore your example array has indices from [0,2]

Comment: I undestand that. I'm unsure on how to fix this though. Because for some tests it works, and for others it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bounds in `partition()` is incorrect. Instead of iterating through the entire array, as you have with

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

You should be iterating over the portion that you are actually partitioning:

```
for (int i = low; i < high; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked, and makes sense!